# backbone model set and unset in same single method call

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

Assume I have one backbone model with state

```
var myModel = new Backbone.Model(
    {
        key1:'value1', 
        key2:'value2', 
        key3:'value3'
    });

myModel.on('all', function allHanlder () {
    console.log(arguments);
})
```

I need remove key1 and key2 and change key3. Possible options are

1. unset key1 and key2 , set key3 attribute
2. clear model and set key3

option 1 results in 3 change, 3 change attribute events

```
myModel.unset('key1');
myModel.unset('key2');
myModel.set({key3:'newValue3'})

//events


["change:key1", Object { cid="c1355", attributes={...}, _changing=true, more...}, undefined, Object { unset=true}]
["change", Object { cid="c1355", attributes={...}, _changing=true, more...}, Object { unset=true}]
["change:key2", Object { cid="c1355", attributes={...}, _changing=true, more...}, undefined, Object { unset=true}]
["change", Object { cid="c1355", attributes={...}, _changing=true, more...}, Object { unset=true}]
["change:key3", Object { cid="c1355", attributes={...}, _changing=true, more...}, "newValue3", Object {}]
["change", Object { cid="c1355", attributes={...}, _changing=true, more...}, Object {}]
```

option 2 will result in 2 change change:attribute events

```
myModel.clear()
myModel.set({key3:'newValue3'})

//output


["change:key1", Object { cid="c1356", attributes={...}, _changing=true, more...}, undefined, Object { unset=true}]
["change:key2", Object { cid="c1356", attributes={...}, _changing=true, more...}, undefined, Object { unset=true}]
["change:key3", Object { cid="c1356", attributes={...}, _changing=true, more...}, undefined, Object { unset=true}]
["change", Object { cid="c1356", attributes={...}, _changing=true, more...}, Object { unset=true}]
["change:key3", Object { cid="c1356", attributes={...}, _changing=true, more...}, "newValue3", Object {}]
["change", Object { cid="c1356", attributes={...}, _changing=true, more...}, Object {}]
```

change:attribute events are fair, but I need to minimise change triggers. Something like below.

```
myModel.someMagicSet({key3:'newValue3'})

//output

["change:key1", Object { cid="c1355", attributes={...}, _changing=true, more...}, undefined, Object {}]
["change:key2", Object { cid="c1355", attributes={...}, _changing=true, more...}, undefined, Object {}]
["change:key3", Object { cid="c1355", attributes={...}, _changing=true, more...}, "newValue3", Object {}]
["change", Object { cid="c1355", attributes={...}, _changing=true, more...}, Object {}]
```

Is there is a way I can achieve it without overriding backbone behaviours?

Comment: I cannot silent changes here. because my change handler need to figure out what all attributes changed/removed.

Comment: If you want your keys to be in the model's attributes, and therefore accessible to `set` and `unset`, change your first code to `var myModel = new Backbone.Model({});  myModel.set({key1:'value1', 
        key2:'value2', 
        key3:'value3'});`

Comment: My code above, and your code in comment both does the same thing, you can verify by executing them

Comment: Actually you are correct, I thought you were creating a model class, but you are creating a model instance. This should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
myModel.unset('key1', {silent: true});
myModel.unset('key2', {silent: true});
myModel.set({key3:'newValue3'}, {removed: ['key1', 'key2']});
```

This will do what you want while only triggering one change event. You are passing in the removed items to your handler in the options object. In your handler, your code should look like this:

```
myModel.on('all', function allHandler (model, options) {
    console.log(options.removed);  // this should show you what has been removed before
    // other code
})
```

Alternately, you could pass a flag in your options with each event which you could analyze in your handler, which would determine whether the handler was run or not. This would give your handler access to what has been changed, but it would have to store it outside of it's own scope in order to access it the next time.

```
myModel.unset('key1', {finished: false});
myModel.unset('key2', {finished: false});
myModel.set({key3:'newValue3'}, {finished: true});
```

**EDIT: Here is a one liner that should do everything:**

```
myModel.clear({reset: {key3: 'newValue3'}});
```

and then in your handler do this

```
myModel.on('all', function allHandler (model, options) {
  if (options.reset){        
    model.set(options.reset);
  }
    // other code
})
```

The thing you should watch out for is that `clear` removes the id too, so if you need that you should pass it in with your options:

```
myModel.clear({reset: {key3: 'newValue3', id: myModel.get('id')}});
```

Comment: If you try to capture changed attributes in change handler, you see only key3.

Comment: @RaviHamsa That is a good point. Let me modify my answer, there is a better but more complicated solution.

Comment: well looks like workable solution, if you are willing manage all removed keys your self. I am looking for more generalised solution, which I can call like `myModel.someMagicSet({key3:'newValue3'})`, similar to `Collection.reset([models])` which remove missing models from collection

Comment: Alright, last try, I added another option at the bottom of my answer. I think it is my favorite, but I haven't been able to test it. Now I am going to visit my family for Christmas!

Comment: `clear` doesn't work the way you think it does: https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L384

Comment: @muistooshort, I thought that `clear` removed all the attributes, and that is what the code seems to indicate. OP indicated in his code that he wanted to clear all the attributes and add a new one.  The new attribute is added in the event listener when the `change` event is fired on the model.  What do you mean?

Comment: But `myModel.clear({key3: 'newValue3', id: myModel.get('id')})` doesn't set `key3` to `'newValue3'` or pay attention to the `id`. `clear` takes an options object, not a set of attributes.

Comment: @muistooshort, exactly, it takes the options object. So you can pass the attributes you want into the options object, and then the handler can set the attributes on the model by using the options object: `myModel.on('all', function allHandler (model, options) {
    model.set(options);
})`

Comment: I edited my answer to make it a little more clear how it works, and to make it so that the handler would only add attributes when you are trying to reset the model, because that handler will be called for every change and you might not always want to set the options object onto the model.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're up to. Might be a good idea to hide those shenanigans behind a custom method though (or even manipulate `attributes` directly and trigger the events by hand), the action-at-a-distance effect could be a bit mystifying in six months.